# Storing large JSON strings in SQL Server using WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a running project using WebAPI and EF code-first.

The database is currently working properly with many tables and relationships set up. However, all my data types are handled as JSON on the client and I don't need to set up extra table for each new nested object in a JSON on the database.

So just as general info, is it bad practice to implement the following example?

object `foo`

- `id` (primary key)
- `value (nvarchar(max))` <- I will store the JSON as string in that column.

assuming `foo` has many nested objects as such `{ 'obj1': '1', 'obj2': [ '123', '456' ] }` etc...

Would that be a good idea? Instead of having `obj1` as a different table and making the relationship back to `foo`.

Thanks

Comment: Certainly this is possible, but if you have consistent data it will be **MUCH** better to actually deserialize the json into actual tables and columns. Also, if you can get to Sql Server 2016, there is (finally) some [built-in json support available.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx)

Comment: I guess it depends, do you need to query the json? If so that will be slow/difficult. As a note mssql 2016 will support json as a native data type.

Comment: Another option for storing JSON is using PostgreSQL that has built-in JSON support http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html. Just only one problem exists - EF can not work with PostgerSQL without tuning.

Comment: What if someone invents a new serialization protocol? Maybe a bit far fetched, but basically you're freezing a transport implementation into a store definition. More realistically: what if you want to expose your data to other parties/APIs, e.g. BI tools?